# Can i make use of binding expression in azure functions for Python?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have in binding of httpTrigger and out binding of blob wherein i am creating a blob after processing the request. The blob name i need to evaluate on runtime and use that in my expression. Is there a way to achive that in python?

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "testcntainer/attachments/{customFileName}",
      "connection": "",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think if you want to use binding to acheive what you want, then it is not possible. The right way is put the logic in the body of your function trigger. Please have a look of my answer.:)

Comment: Hi, any update of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is no possible.

The value of blobname in binding is const.

The right way to acheive what you want is put the logic in the body of your function.

Have a look of this offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#upload-blobs-to-a-container

Let me know if you have any adoubts about above link, if that, I will update a simple code.:)

Comment: Its not possible at all or just not possible in python runtime env?

Comment: @ManinderChhabra Yes, all of them is not possible. Not just Python. Please put the dynamic param in body of function and do the logic in the body.